# Splitting a string and validating it using Angular 2 and Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I would like to replicate the following situation:

I have a string, let's say

```
 123BCP456GF789
```

I want to split it in the half and ask the user to insert the missing numbers and validate it if it's correct.

It will be like this:

```
123B <ion-input></ion-input> F789
```

I'm using Angular 2 and Ionic 2 to do this, if anyone can help me, I appreciate.

Let's say I have this array:

```
numberList = ['123BCP456GF789', '46487951', '65135564', '46489633'];

          <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label stacked primary>Complete with the mising number</ion-label>
                    <ion-item>{{numberList_firstpart}}</ion-item>
                    <ion-input></ion-input>
                    <ion-item>{{numberList_lastpart}}</ion-item>
                </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution, independent from AngularJs, can be:

```
var numberList = ['123BCP456GF789', '46487951', '65135564', '46489633'];

numberList.forEach(function(element) {

    //total length of the string
    var elLength = element.length;

    //get the max number of characters usable for first and second part
    var singleElementLength = Math.ceil(elLength/3);

    //the first part of the string
    var firstPart = element.substring(0, singleElementLength);

    //the last part of the string
    var lastPart = element.substring(element.length-singleElementLength, element.length);

    //this one should be entered by user
    var middlePart = element.replace(firstPart, '').replace(lastPart, '');

    console.log(firstPart);
    console.log(middlePart);
    console.log(lastPart);


});
```

The output will be:

```
"123BC"
"P456"
"GF789"

"464"
"87"
"951"

"651"
"35"
"564"

"464"
"89"
"633"
```

If you want, you can use `Math.floor()` instead of `Math.ceil()`: doing this will cause to have the middle part longer, please see the outputs below:

```
"123B"
"CP456G"
"F789"

"46"
"4879"
"51"

"65"
"1355"
"64"

"46"
"4896"
"33"
```

Please note: in order to use this method you must have string with, at least, 3 characters (probably more, depends what you use between `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()`). I would suggest you add some controls for this.

Comment: Up-voting this because it didn't occur to me that https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572652/math-loures also needs help with splitting `numberList`. Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is two-fold:

1. Capturing user input, and
2. Comparing the user input against the correct answer

To capture user input, it's binding the data entry whenever the user keys in text, e.g.

```
<ion-input (keyup)="captureInput($event)"></ion-input>
```

There's more than one way to capture data entry. It depends on when you want to compare against the correct answer (e.g. on a button click, loss of focus, etc.)

The last part is the comparison against the correct answer, which I think you can solve with a standard Javascript regex test, eg..

```
/the correct answer/.test(`${ this.first_part }${ this.input }${ this.last_part }`)
```

Your actual implementation will dictate the coding particulars, but hopefully you get the gist of what I'm saying.

Hope this helps.